# Copy a non-Python file to specific directory during Pip Install

Tags: python, setup.py

Problem Statement: when I install my pip package, a specific file inside the package get coped to `Temp` directory

Approach:

My Package directory Sturcture is following:

```
my-app/
├─ app/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ __main__.py
├─ folder-with-extra-stuff/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ file_I_want_to_cppy.tar.gz 
├─ setup.py
├─ MANIFEST.in
```

I'm tweaking my setup.py file to do the job. Following is my `setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.install import install
import os
import sys
import shutil

rootDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

def run_custom_install():
 
    print("--------Start running custom command -------")
    temp_dir = r'c:\temp' if sys.platform == "win32" else r'/tmp'
    temp_col_dir = temp_dir + os.sep + 'dump'
    os.makedirs(temp_dir, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(temp_col_dir, exist_ok=True)
    print("----------locate the zip file ---------------")
    ColDirTests = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(rootDir, 'my-app','folder-with-extra-stuff'))
    _src_file = os.path.join(ColDirTests , 'file_I_want_to_cppy.tar.gz ')
    print(f"******{_src_file}**********")
    if os.path.exists(_src_file):
        print(f"-----zip file has been located at {_src_file}")
        shutil.copy(_src_file, temp_col_dir)
    else:
        print("!!!!Couldn't locate the zip file for transfer!!!!")

class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        print("***********Custom run from install********")
        install.run(self)
        run_custom_install()

ver = "0.0.0"
setup(
    name='my_pkg',
    version=ver,
    packages=find_packages(),
    python_requires='>=3.6.0',
    install_requires = getRequirements(),
    include_package_data= True,
    cmdclass={
            'install' : CustomInstall,
            }
     )
```

MANIFEST.in

```
include README.md
include file_I_want_to_cppy.tar.gz
recursive-include my-app *
global-exclude *.pyc
include requirements.txt
prune test
```

Testing build:

```
> python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

It is working during build. I can see there is a directory formed `C:\temp\dump` and `file_I_want_to_cppy.tar.gz` inside it. But when I release the package in pip and try to install it from pip, the folder remains Empty!

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Files in the temp directory are not guaranteed to persist. It does not sound wise to install anything there.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks. I can change the directory in future. Issue is that the tar.gz file not getting copied when I pip install the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I have figure out how to resolve this issue. Let me summarize my findings, it might be helpful for other who wants to do `post_pip_install` processing.

#### setup.py

- Different options to install package: 1) `pip install pkg_name`, 2) `python -m setup.py sdist`
- If you want to make them work in either ways, need to have `install`, `egg_info` and `develop` all 3 options repeated as shown in setup.py
- If you create `*.whl` file by `python -m setup.py bdist_wheel` , `post pip install processing` **won't be executed!** Please upload `.tar.gz` format generated using`sdist` to PyPi/Artifacts to make `post pip install processing` work. Again, Please note: **It will not work when installing from a binary wheel**
- upload the pip package: `twine upload dist/*.tar.gz`

  ```
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
    from setuptools.command.install import install
    from setuptools.command.egg_info import egg_info
    from setuptools.command.develop import develop


    rootDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    def run_post_processing():

        print("--------Start running custom command -------")
        # One can Run any Post Processing here that will be executed post pip install 

    class PostInstallCommand(install):
        def run(self):
            print("***********Custom run from install********")
            install.run(self)
            run_post_processing()

    class PostEggCommand(egg_info):
        def run(self):
            print("***********Custom run from Egg********")
            egg_info.run(self)
            run_post_processing()

    class PostDevelopCommand(develop):
        def run(self):
            print("***********Custom run from Develop********")
            develop.run(self)
            run_post_processing()

    ver = "0.0.0"
    setup(
        name='my_pkg',
        version=ver,
        packages=find_packages(),
        python_requires='>=3.6.0',
        install_requires = getRequirements(),
        include_package_data= True,
        cmdclass={
                'install' : PostInstallCommand,
                'egg_info': PostEggCommand,
                'develop': PostDevelopCommand
                }
         )
  ```

#### Few More Things from my research:

1. If you want to do `pre-processing` instead of `post-processing`, need to move  `install.run(self)` at the end
2. while pip installing, if you want to see custom messages of pre/post instllation, use `-vvv`. Example: `pip install -vvv my_pkg`